# fadeOut without collapse

Tags: jquery

I have a list that I would like to fadeOut, but not have it collapse.
The documentation says "Once the opacity reaches 0, the display style property is set to none".

I wonder if I could fadeOut down to 1 or something.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Have you tried using jQuery's [fadeTo()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) function and then setting it to a 0 opacity? Something like this:

```
$('#myDiv').fadeTo('medium', 0);
```

Answer (score 7):

How about just [using `.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to animate the `opacity` to 0 instead of using the `.fadeOut()` method?

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZqBGa/

```
$( selector ).animate({opacity: 0});
```

This will retain the element in the page structure, but it will be invisible.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the list in a div with a set height, then fade out the list.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/CtQcR/